# NinjectWebCommon.cs file is not adding after install ninject nuget package

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ninject.web.mvc

I am using one web api application where i need to add ninject for dependency injection. I have gone through this [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-web-api-with-repository-pattern-and-dependency-injection/) where steps is mentioned one by one to use ninject. Currently i am using MVC 5 so for that i found ninjectMVC5 in nuget. I installed it but according to this link i should have get NinjectWebCommon.cs file in App_Start folder but did not get any file there to register our component.

I uninstalled all the ninject packages and found another [link](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/) and followed there steps but still ninjectwebcommon.cs file is not finding in app_start folder.

Can someone explain here what i am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Vikash

Comment: Look at [this issue on github](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/35). You can downgrade the Ninject nuget package to 3.2.3, or add the NinjectWebCommon.cs by hand.

Comment: @Goat, Thanks for the solution. I tried to downgrade inject nuget version to 3.2.3 and now the NinjectWebCommon.cs file got added already. Please send your suggestion as answer i will upvote it and make this converstation closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/35) on github says that downgrading Ninject to version 3.2.3 should resolve the issue. Another option is to add the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` manually.